# Can you use the chain rule when only one partial derivative is continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Say the partial derivative with respect to $x$ of some function $f(x,y,z)$ exists and/or continuous, but the other partial derivatives don't exist. Can I still apply the chain rule if I'm only differentiating with respect to $x$?

Comment: For fixed $y, z$ this is simply a differentiable function of $x$, so yes. Both for $g\circ f$ and $f(g(t), y, z)$.

Comment: If a partial derivative doesn't exist, does that necessarily mean that the respective variable is fixed?

Comment: No, you just keep the variables fixed and look at the result as a function of $x$

Comment: But if the total derivative of $f$ doesn't exist, then it has no implications on using the chain rule for any partial derivative of that function $f$ that does exist?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.